# Spring Boot's spring-boot:run doesn't honor specified profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am upgrading my old spring boot 1.5.x to latest 2.0.4, and I found `mvn spring-boot:run` doesn't honor the profile specified in command line:

I have an `application.properties` which stores common properties, and `application-dev.properties` and `application-prod.properties` specifying their db connections and tomcat ports.

It means, I have two profiles: `dev` and `prod`. I lookup the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html), I have to specify profiles in `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <profiles>
      <profile>dev</profile>
      <profile>prod</profile>
    </profiles>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And I want to execute the `dev` profile, I run:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
```

And I see console outputs

```
boot.SpringApplication - The following profiles are active: dev
```

It seems Ok, but then I found it connects to wrong database and open different port, which is specified in `prod` profile.

It seems all values specified in `prod` override the `dev` ones.

And if I comment the values in `prod`, the `dev` ones are pickup (so, there is no typo in `dev` profile).

I tried the following combos:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles="dev"
mvn spring-boot:run -Pdev -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
mvn spring-boot:run -Pdev -Dspring-boot.run.profiles="dev"
```

All show `The following profiles are active: dev` but connect to `prod` DB and open wrong tomcat port.

I then tried:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Pdev -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
mvn spring-boot:run -Pdev -Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
```

All the 5 above show `The following profiles are active: dev,prod` (which is incorrect, I just want `dev`) and still connect to `prod` DB

What may go wrong here?

This was easy in spring boot 1.5.x but became a WTF in 2.0.x . I feel frustrated here.

env:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

------- updated -------

As @Jayesh said , maybe there's something wrong hidden, which leads default to `prod`. I renamed my `application-prod.properties` to `application-prod2.properties`. I am sure there's no `prod2` string in the whole project code.

after `mvn clean compile install`,

Rerun with

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
```

Same result (`The following profiles are active: dev` but still opens to wrong DB specified in `prod2`)

And...

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Same result: `The following profiles are active: dev,prod`, connects to wrong DB, opens wrong port specified in `prod2`

**It seems spring boot picks whatever `application-*.properties` and load the last one**

I even set log level to TRACE

```
logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
```

But still found no `prod2` string in the output log...

---

## Solved

The problem is solved.

There is another spring's XML containing this line:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties"/>
```

It is the culprit. After commenting out this line, everything works fine.

P.S.: This is an evolving app, from pure spring app, with spring's XML setting, and the above line. Then wrapped in MVC, and then spring-boot . Everything works fine in 1.5.x, but in 2.x, boot truly loaded all `.properties` files and override all value one by one.

Comment: may be there's another property file with prod specific configs or you're defaulting the configs to prod ?

Comment: @Jayesh I updated the question. I rename `application-prod.properties` to `application-prod2.properties` and still get the same result... This is very annoying ...

Comment: thats really annoying.. may be try `@PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.active.profile}.properties")` on your Configuration ?

Comment: If this is solved then please accept the answer that resolved this for you, or add your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK , The problem is solved.

There is another spring's XML containing this line :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties"/>
```

It is the culprit. After commenting out this line , everything works fine.

P.S. : This is an evolving app , from pure spring app , with spring's XML setting , and the above line. Then wrapped in MVC , and then spring-boot . Everything works fine in 1.5.x , but in 2.x , boot truly loaded all `.properties` files and override all value one by one.

Maybe there are some subtle changes on parsing `.properties` from spring boot 1.5.x to 2.x.

Comment: please mark is as correct answer so that everyone doesnt see this as unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

Please update your pom.xml without the profiles section. As per [boot maven plugin doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html), you should only provide active profile in the section.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <profiles>
      <!--<profile>dev</profile>
      <profile>prod</profile>   you are setting active profile via command line args-->
    </profiles>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Since, you are passing via command line args you dont need to give it there..  You may look at these beautiful tutorials.

1. https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profiles-example/
2. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks , both `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev` and `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev` not working. Both show `The following profiles are active: dev` but still use `prod2` profile , which `prod2` String doesn't exist in my code base.

I am trying to rebuild my project piece by piece . Because there are many modules within ( kotlin , gRPC ...) , Maybe some bug within.

Comment: Sorry, I didint get you. Did you comment out or remove the profile in pom.xml section and Is it working now??

Comment: Yes , I comment out `<profiles>` section but still not working.

Comment: What are the names of your application.property files?

Comment: `application.properties` , `application-dev.properties` , `application-prod.properties` (and now `application-prod2.properties` , which `prod2` never exists in my code base , but still got chosen. weird.)

Comment: Can you give details of your application.properties file and the command you use to run the jar? (Did you clean and build again)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178843/discussion-between-anand-varkey-philips-and-smallufo).

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the latest Spring Boot(v2.0.4.RELEASE) and the profile are getting loaded as expected.

**pom.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <profiles>
            <profile>dev</profile>
            <profile>prod</profile>
          </profiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

**TestController.java**:

```
package com.example.demo.TestController;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * Created by Raj Rathore on 27-Aug-18
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

  @Value("${profile}")
  String profile;

  @GetMapping("/profile")
  public String getProfile() {
    return profile;
  }

}
```

**application-dev.poperties**:

```
profile=dev profile
```

**application-pord.poperties**:

```
profile=prod profile
```

Then by using the `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev` the `dev` profile is loaded :

> com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : The following profiles are active: dev

**Output** : (http://localhost:8080/test/profile)

dev profile